# Get value of attribute inside input tag using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, ios

I have tried to get the value from an attribute inside an `<input>` element using JavaScript, but the result is not shown. Here is my code:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('button').getAttribute('onClick')[0].innerHTML;
```

And here is my HTML:

```
<input type="button" class="button" value="Login to download" onclick="js:self.location='login.php?ret=view&b=55212'"><br/>
```

I want to get the value inside `onclick`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```js
document.getElementsByClassName('button')[0].getAttribute('onClick')
```

This will give you

```js
js:self.location='login.php?ret=view&b=55212'
```

Answer (score 2):

```
getElementsByClassName
```

returns array

Not the

```
getAttribute
```

So

```
document.getElementsByClassName('button').getAttribute('onClick')[0].innerHTML;
```

Should be

```
document.getElementsByClassName('button')[0].getAttribute('onClick');
```

And

```
 onClick  != onclick
```

Comment: What you want then ? not the full string ?